# How can I resolve "Error: No developer directory found at /Developer"?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild

I just upgraded XCode to 4.3.1.
I'm using a script to build (and then deploy through Testflight) my app.
But I now receive this error:

> Error: No developer directory found at /Developer. Run /usr/bin/xcode-select to update the developer directory path.

I've no /Developer dir in my machine: how can I fix it?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: And what do I do if that doesn't work? I do exactly the you say, get no error, and then do "xcodebuild -version" and get the error "Error: No developer directory found at /Developer. Run /usr/bin/xcode-select to update the developer directory path."

Comment: It doesn't sound like xcode-select ran properly.  Double-check that the path is set correctly by running `xcode-select -print-path`.

Comment: got this warning when updating MacPorts via `sudo port selfupdate`, perfect solution!

Comment: Happens because from about Xcode 4.2 Apple started distributing it as an app, downloadable from the App Store. Consequently, all tools are installed in the Applications/Xcode.app package.

Comment: I had to create a soft link pointing /Developer to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/. That's the only solution I could find.

Comment: xcode-select --print-path gives me /Developer. If I do the above, then it's still /Developer. I can't seem to change it. Doing a build gives me "xcrun: error: unable to find Xcode installation". It's not fixed if I create a soft link to /Developer. This is very frustrating.

Comment: New path seems to be /Library/Developer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780858/xcode-4-5-command-line-tools-xcode-select-issue

Comment: This answer was helpful to me because I received the error upon attempting to run `cordova build` , when I was following the cordova ios platform guides( http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide ). Other people trying to follow along with those guides might have the same problem I did.

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this instead ...

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer /Developer
```

Comment: It's an attempt to hide the problem, not fix it.  If you do that, all of the tools are still looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Even after doing this command i get this error xcode-select: Error: Path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" is not a directory. There is no Developer directory even after doing this command

Answer (score 3):

Everything you guys answered is correct. But for those who hit the following error are missing a step:

Error:

```
  "xcode-select: Error: Path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" is not a directory."
```

Missing step:

```
Double click your xcode 432.dmg. Now don't double click the xcode.app to use it. Instead copy it /Applications folder and then open it from there to install xcode.
```

Now use terminal command

```
 sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Thats it. Your error won't happen again and
 Filemerge will work now.

Comment: Nice, should be noted that not putting xcode into applications can cause this

Answer (score 2):

This solved for me:

Mostly this error occurs when you have installed a newer version of xcode. And the command line tools are yet to be initialized.

To resolve this: Go under Xcode Preferences > Locations (tab) > And the bottom options is Command Line Tools. Please select the Xcode version for tools.

Example (For Xcode 8.3.3): Go under Xcode Preferences > Locations (tab) > And the bottom options is Command Line Tools. Select Xcode 8.3.3 (7D1014).