# Can I install Valgrind on Mac OS X 10.7.4 without having Xcode?

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, valgrind

I have been searching for quite some time now as to whether there is a way by which I can install Valgrind without the need of installing Xcode, knowing that I have apple's Command Line Tools already installed. During the installing of Valgrind I get the following:

```
Making all in coregrind
(cd m_mach && mig /usr/include/mach/mach_vm.defs /usr/include/mach/task.defs /usr/include/mach/thread_act.defs /usr/include/mach/vm_map.defs)
xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app to select /Applications/Xcode.app, or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.
/usr/bin/mig: line 174: Error: /usr/bin/xcode-select returned unexpected error.: No such file or directory
mig: fatal: "<no name yet>", line -1: no SubSystem declaration
make[2]: *** [m_mach/mach_vmUser.c] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there is `xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected` message.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9621787/432914) out.