# Xcode 4.5 Command Line Tools - xcode-select issue

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

After installing Xcode CLT 4.5.1 on OS X 10.8.2, I'm having issues installing native ruby gems which need to compiled.

The output error is the same as with running xcrun -find:

> xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch , or
>   see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.

To which CLT location should *xcode-select* point to, since it's no longer at /Developer?

Edit: I don't have the Xcode app installed, only CLT.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The new location seems to be (be sure to run as root):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/
```

Comment: This does the trick, which is kinda weird considering that this directory only contains an `Acknowledgements.rtf`.

Comment: I was hoping this would work for Ruby Motion as well, but no luck.  That may, unfortunately, need for XCode to be installed in its entirety.

Comment: use _sudo !!_ to avoid to paste again

Answer (score 11):

Since your Xcode tools are installed in /usr/bin, you should

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /
```

Comment: the `-switch /` command does not work, but `-switch /Library/Developer` does.  CLT installed.

Answer (score 5):

With XCode 4.5 installed AND Command Line Tools installed, I had to use this to get MacPorts and other similar things (like Ruby Gems or Perl CPAN module installation) working:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
```

I found that /Library/Developer did not work.  Note that the Developer folder is not under /Library for me, it's under the app bundle file content folders.

I'm not sure why this is, but people googling this issue may come here and want to know the other commandline options that are commonly usable with xcode-select, thus this answer, even though it doesn't 100% apply to the original question (where command line tools are installed WITHOUT XCode).

Answer (score 2):

you *probably* want:

```
xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

unless you have multiple installs.  that is likely the location if you have one install (e.g. from the App Store). if you have multiple installs, you probably know which one you want.

you could also try updating this value from Xcode's `Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools` popup.

Comment: @DustMason yes. it was mentioned… in response to my answer (including an edit to the OP).

Answer (score 1):

Open XCode and go to preferences.

Verify that there is an option under "Command Line Tools"

The error went away for me, as soon as I specified my Xcode command line tools version. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I got further from @jbowes `xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/` answer, but then I hit this:

```
xcrun: Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)
```

I came across this thread ([OSX 10.8 xcrun (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041525/osx-10-8-xcrun-no-such-file-or-directory)) which references a Gist that solved my problem:

https://gist.github.com/thelibrarian/5520597

It's gross, but it seems to be the only way to solve the issue with just the Command Line Tools (i.e. not a full-blown XCode installation).