# Find out the path location to Command Line Tools for Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-command-line-tools

I didn't want to install the whole Xcode, so I just downloaded the command line tools for Xcode. I am trying to install ruby 1.9.3 via rvm. However, rvm complains that no xcode is selected:

> xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch , or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.

I read the `xcode-select` manpage and I know how to set the path to the Xcode Command Line Tools, but I don't know where they are installed. How do I find this out?

I am using OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: For those who are looking to find out the path of the command line tools: Enter `xcode-select -p` in Terminal

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The entries in `/usr/bin` are just a front for whatever you choose with `xcode-select`:

```
$> /usr/bin/clang --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

The standalone command line tools are installed in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`:

```
$> sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$> /usr/bin/clang --version
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: I have to say thank you here. If you want c compiler without Xcode (more than 10G), just download command line tools and then follow this guideline.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:
`sudo xcode-select --reset`

Comment: Worked for me too after I ran `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 3):

If you have your user folder on an external drive, this worked for me:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

For a standalone install.

Answer (score 2):

Short version: the answer to my problem is to install the full Xcode, not only the Command Line Tools.

Long version:

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041525/osx-10-8-xcrun-no-such-file-or-directory) I found out, that the location of the tools is /usr/bin . So I ran `sudo xcode-select -switch /usr/bin`. After that however, I got this error:

> Error: failed to exec real xcrun. (No such file or directory)

So based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041525/osx-10-8-xcrun-no-such-file-or-directory) I install the full Xcode app, ran `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and this solved my problem.

Comment: This seems to be required for earlier versions of XCode, for example, XCode 8.3.3 which is the latest version that will run on OSX Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

this is not warning from RVM, most likely it is displayed by Homebrew, I got few complains about it but it was always harmless and installation of ruby completed without problems.

if you get errors show all of them not just one.