# Homebrew cannot find installed command line tools

Tags: xcode, homebrew

I have installed command line tools through Xcode. When I ran `xcode-select -p`, its showed `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

However, when I ran `brew config`, it showed `CLT: N/A`. And when I updated python using brew, it showed `Warning: Building python from source: The bottle needs the Apple Command Line Tools to be installed.`

Comment: Always always state both the version of MacOS and of Xcode, since Apple keeps changing their behavior (and directories, and command-line interface) every coupla versions... Also helps to state your version of brew.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've got the same issue just now. Running `xcode-select --install` to reinstall Command Line Tools worked for me, `brew config` now reports `CLT: 7.3.1.0.1.1461711523`.

Comment: Seems this needs to happen even if Xcode CLI is installed (Big Sur) - It may be because there is an additional prompt for accepting EULA when running `xcode-select --install` - haven't tested just accepting it without reinstalling, but the reinstall plus acceptance did fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

As `xcode-select --install` did not solve the issue for me:

I had to run `brew doctor` which listed `Warning: Some installed formula are missing dependencies.` including a brew install command to fix these. After running that, `brew config` reported `CLT` no longer as `N/A`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help for me. Seems like Xcode 8.3.3 full install isn't recognized for CLT by homebrew.

Comment: neither worked for me , xcode-select --install resulted in 
'xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates ' but there werent any more updates to be installed .

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed the standalone version of the CLI tools (and don't have the full xcode application):

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

(path courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008480/758177)

Answer (score 0):

For the same  [dependency issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGtVe.png) above,
`xcode-select --install` and clicking "Install" on the [pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJPle.png) fixes this in MacOS Catalina. Once complete, you can confirm it by typing `xcode-select -v` in the terminal and the output should look similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojpv0.png)