# Installing mcrypt on OSX 10.8.2 - PHP 5.3.15 with homebrew

Tags: php, mcrypt

I've successfully installed `mcrypt` via `homebrew` but I'm struggling to find the path to `mcrypt.so` to include it as an extension in `php.ini`.

mcrypt was installed at `/usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8`. Tree:

```
-- AUTHORS
|-- ChangeLog
|-- INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
|-- NEWS
|-- README
|-- TODO
|-- bin
|   `-- libmcrypt-config
|-- include
|   |-- mcrypt.h
|   `-- mutils
|       `-- mcrypt.h
|-- lib
|   |-- libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
|   |-- libmcrypt.4.dylib -> libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
|   `-- libmcrypt.dylib -> libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
`-- share
    |-- aclocal
    |   `-- libmcrypt.m4
    `-- man
        `-- man3
            `-- mcrypt.3
```

I tried to include `mcrypt.h` in `php.ini`:

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8/include/mcrypt.h"
```

and then restarted apache.
but it didn't work.

when I run php in the terminal I get:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8/include/mcrypt.h' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/mcrypt/2.5.8/include/mcrypt.h, 9): 
image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Why is it installed there?

Comment: That is where homebrew installed it...

Comment: Is that what homebrew does with every package?  I.e. rather than put libraries into `/usr/local/lib` it creates a directory for each?

Comment: it seems like it keeps all the packages at `/usr/local/Cellar/[pkg_name]/[pkg_version]`

Comment: I use macports and now I know why.  That is much more sensible about installing packages.  I would recommend ditching homebrew and trying macports instead...

Comment: Homebrew works just fine. All you needed to do was to tap the recommended php formula, and install php from within Homebrew itself
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
$ brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
$ brew install php54
$ brew install php54-mcrypt

Comment: Thanks @Gazzer. I believe it is better to add it as an answer

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First check if brew is up-to-date:
`brew doctor`

Second install mcrypt based on php version:
`brew install php53-mcrypt`

*NB: Step three below is not required on recent versions of brew:*

Third open php.ini file and add reference:
`sudo vi /private/etc/php.ini`
`extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php53-mcrypt/5.3.25/mcrypt.so"`

Finally, restart apache:
`sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: For someone trying to only use homebrew this was useful.

Comment: When I did `brew install php53-mcrypt`, brew told me it wasn't found, but mentioned a 'tap'. So I did `brew tap josegonzalez/php` to add that tap, and then ran `brew install php53-mcrypt` again, which installed a bunch of stuff, but eventually worked.

Comment: Today with recent versions of the softwares only `brew install php56-mcrypt` is necessary.

Comment: @TylerCollier Ditto over here.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson - yep.  I am using php 5.5 and got an error after adding `extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php55-mcrypt/5.5.30/mcrypt.so"` so removed it and everything works now.

Comment: `brew install php56-mcrypt` worked for me in Yosemite and also did not include the extension in php.ini.

Comment: Note, the reference to tapping josegonzalez above is out of date now, his work has now been made the official branch. `brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php` will get you what you need

Answer (score 22):

After wondering for hours through different advices, [this one](http://www.gigoblog.com/2011/01/27/add-mcrypt-to-mac-os-x-server/comment-page-1/#comment-3897) worked for me (Installed via MacPorts):

Courtesy of **Chris Brewer**:

Download and install MacPorts from `http://macports.org.`

The following steps are performed in the Terminal:

Force MacPorts to update (will only work if Apple's Xcode installed):

```
sudo port -v selfupdate
```

Now, install memcached:

```
sudo port install php5-mcrypt
```

Copy the newly created shared object for mcrypt into Mac OS X’s default PHP5 extension directory:

```
sudo cp /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/
```

Next, you need to edit php.ini to add the extensions. Find the phrase Dynamic Extensions, and add:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

And finally, restart Apache:

`sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I am on os x mountain lion and nothing else seemed to work!

Comment: old info now use sudo port install php53-mcrypt

Answer (score 9):

I've solved the problem with this

```
brew install php54-mcrypt --without-homebrew-php
```

Then I add this line to `/etc/php.ini`.

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.24/mcrypt.so"
```

If this file doesn't exists you'll need to copy it from `/etc/php.ini.default`. Also I check the version of my php with `php -v` (And it was 5.4.x)

Comment: That's what I needed. Just had to do this first: brew tap josegonzalez/php

Comment: Error: No available formula for php54-mcrypt

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the work you did on this! This worked for me. I am on a mac and it was looking for xcode. The Developer location hadn't been set so I had to do all of this.

(RESOLVE THE DEVELOPER PATH)
[How can I resolve "Error: No developer directory found at /Developer"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621706/how-can-i-resolve-error-no-developer-directory-found-at-developer)

1. sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

(SIGN THE AGREEMENT TO USE XCODE)

2. sudo xcodebuild -license

Lastly follow the above steps!

Answer (score 0):

Worked like a piece of cake with [this](http://benohead.com/mac-os-x-php-notice-use-undefined-constant-mcrypt_rijndael_128/).

```
$ brew install mcrypt
Warning: mcrypt-2.6.8 already installed
$ brew install php55-mcrypt
Warning: php55-mcrypt-5.5.20 already installed
```

Then test it out:

```
$ php -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt

$ php -i | grep mcrypt
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
```

Answer (score 0):

This may prove useful...

1. brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
2. brew install php56-mcrypt