# I install mcrypt by homebrew , and phpmyadmin still tell me it's missing

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

Sorry for ask this simple question, but I really can't find any useful information for mcrypr extension missing.

I code PHP on my Mac air, at first time. I sucked in every package's building, and every details was gone and crash,so,I reinstall all my OS and upgrade to OS X 10.8.

I read some tutorials about homebrew, second time, after I enable apache and PHP (already in OS X), I download homebrew and install mysql and mcrypt, and put PhpMyAdmin that download from official website in `/Library/WebServer/Document/`.

The steps I use was:

1. brew install mysql <= this is command i use , not just describe my action
2. brew install mcrypt <= command
3. make mysql startup when booting
4. add new line: extension = mcrypt.so in php.ini.default and rename to php.ini.
5. set mysql root name and pw.

Every log about install was right and success, the folder Cellar was there in `/usr/local/`. Folder mcrypt was there too.

But when I login phpMyAdmin,still find the line: mcrypt extension is missing still there

Some step I miss or, I add wrong line in php.ini?

And another question, if we install mysql by homebrew, and the charset will set to UTF-8 automatically? Cause my system show me this before i edit `my.cnf` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ...... I find a answer for my question.

In this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357107/installing-mcrypt-on-osx-10-8-2-php-5-3-15-with-homebrew),even question in this post was different from mine,but there is a very important idea I forgot.

At last , I use macports to create the same environment of PHP+Apache at /opt/local/xxxx/xxx
,homebrew is different from macports,macports didn't depend system's lib or files as much as possible,so I try to use macports and install mcrypt by:

sudo port install php5-mcrypt

when it's done,I copy crypt.so to php/extension/xxxx/xxxx , and it's work finally,maybe someone can reference this kind of answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should restart Apache so it can notice the newly-installed PHP extension.

Comment: thank you ... ... but you know,I really did restart,and still fails,btw thank you again :)