# Need help installing mcrypt for a php dev environment on Mac High Sierra

Tags: php, macos, mcrypt, macos-high-sierra

I've spent the better part of a day researching this. Yesterday, I updated my Mac laptop to High Sierra. That updated the Server app, which runs my dev environment. The environment is fine except that I can't get mcrypt installed. Mac HS comes with PHP 5.6.30 and I've gone through these steps (https://michaelgracie.com/2016/09/plugging-mcrypt-into-php-on-macos-sierra-10-12/) multiple times.  I get to the step where I run

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.13 CFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-O3 -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64' ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
```

But it returns:

> -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: That's great advice - thanks!  We'll look into moving to those 2 options asap.  In the meantime, though, I still need to get my local dev env working so I can work on the current codebase.  So again, any help in getting this specific issue resolved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem as you, as i had updated to high Sierra yesterday and screw my dev environment. I finally found out High Sierra comes already with Php71 so the one i already had install was been override, so what i did was this:

`for i in $(brew list | grep php); do brew uninstall $i; done`

it got my php working now all i did was install

`brew install php71-mcrypt php71-imagick`

boom worked like a charm for me, hope it helps you or anyone else

All this was from the terminal

also this link may help you as well

https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

Comment: I tried this solution, but nothing changed.  It's very strange.  Mcrypt *seems* to be installed, but it doesn't appear in phpinfo.  Any ideas?

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357107/installing-mcrypt-on-osx-10-8-2-php-5-3-15-with-homebrew

Comment: I was really hoping... but no.  It's still not allowing me to install mcrypt.  Actually, I shouldn't say it that way.  It *seems* like it's being installed, but it's not working.  phpinfo doesn't show any setting for mcrypt.

Comment: Try adding the path to the mcrypt to your php.ini I add it mine at the end of the file this is how it looks like .     extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php71-mcrypt/7.1.11_17/mcrypt.so