# Install mcrypt extension for php with Homebrew in Mac High Sierra

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, mcrypt

I've been trying to install mcrypt extension for php 5.6 with the next commands:

```
brew install php56-mcrypt
```

with no results, I'm getting this error:

> No available formula with the name "php56-mcrypt"

taken from questions like these:

[Installing mcrypt on OSX 10.8.2 - PHP 5.3.15 with homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357107/installing-mcrypt-on-osx-10-8-2-php-5-3-15-with-homebrew/14359504)

According with this issue opened at Github:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4721

this way seemed was valid until March 2018, and now there's a new formula that I haven't been able to figure out.

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: considered php 7? and pdo?

Comment: Be aware that the mcrypt extension has been ***DEPRECEATED*** in version 7.1 of PHP and will very likely be ***REMOVED*** from version 7.2 of PHP

Comment: @smith I need the extension because in the project is being used Laravel 4.2

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Project will be migrated to Laravel version 5 soon, I think this version does not require mcrypt

Comment: @JoseRojas did you get to the bottom of this. I have the same for a Laravel 4.2 project which needs running.